# When installing Ubuntu installation wizard freezes

Tags: system-installation, asus

I got an old laptop, an Asus ASUS-ZenBook-UX32VD that cannot boot up.

Im trying to install ubuntu on the harddrive but im getting stuck when running the installation wizard on the step when it asks you to connect to the wifi or not (see image below). When I click continue the "working" mouse symbol appears but nothing happens. I waited for 20 minutes without getting any futher.

This is my first time trying to install linux so im not sure how it should usually go. This is what I have tried so far:

- created an bootable usb from ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso with rufus.
- created an bootable usb from this release too Linux Mint 19.3 "Tricia" - Cinnamon (64-bit). Got stuck in the installation wizard the exact same way as before.
- I have tried with different usb sticks but i always get stuck on the same step.

Windows was installed before and when trying to boot you are getting this error when booting up:

> BlinitializeLibrary failed 0xc000000bb

After some googling I found that you could try to write these commands in the command prompt.

```
Bootrec / fixmbr
Bootrec / fixboot
Bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/bi-initializelibrary-failed-0xc00000bb-on-black/a8889e67-300c-491a-965a-df087ab5cbe1

But I cant boot up windows from USB stick (I tried). I can boot up linux from USB, but cannot install. I tried to write the commands in the terminal when booting from usb but the commands were not found.

At this point Im just been guessing on what to do but I have tried to disable secure boot in bios and reinstalling bios (same version as before which was the latest) with easy flash. It did nothing.

Any suggestions on what to do would be greatly appreciated!
Otherwise I guess my laptop is doomed..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a failing SSD drive.
So,

1. What kind of HDD is installed?  if SSD this appears to be a lot like what I've dealt with before.
2. What are the settings in UEFI/BIOS for hdd access? (i.e. Intel's Speedstor, etc.) and was that changed lately?
3. How "old" is "old"?  That will give some context to possibilities.   i.e. you may try an older release of Ubuntu/Kubuntu such as from 2016, or a recovery based distro that can check the disk and let you know.  It's been a while since I've used one of these, but distrowatch, has a list. (or used to).

Comment: Hello Howard

Maybe you are right. 
1. The harddrive is not a ssd but it could be failing one.
2. Not sure what bios this is, cant find anything in the bios menu that resembles what you are referring to but I guess its the default setting.
3. My laptop is from 2012. Its this one: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX32VD/. Thats a good idea, I could try that.

Comment: Hey ir worked with a new ssd, Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you have it figured out.  It sucks when drives go bad slowly, because it makes finding the real problem hard, but it also gives you time to get your data off.